# How to sort a Rust Vector with map-like closures?

Tags: sorting, rust, iterator, closures

I'd like to sort a Vector of structs, using some sort of closure-like format. Here's what I was thinking:

```rs
struct PointTracker {
    positive: u32,
    negative: u32,
}

// ....

fn main() {
    let item: Vec<PointTracker> // ....

    // e.g: [{positive: 3, negative: 4}, {positive: 5, negative: 0}, {positive: 2, negative: 10}]
    
    let sorted_item = item
        .iter()
        .sort_with(|x: PointTracker| x.positive - x.negative)
        .collect::<PointTracker>();

    // sorted from greatest to least:
    // [{positive: 5, negative: 0}, {positive: 3, negative: 4}, {positive:2, negative: 10}]
}
```

What I was looking for is some sort of function, like above, that sorts items based on the value returned in the closure. This takes the positive value, subtracts the negative from it, and returns the result. The first unsorted items' sums would be: `[-1, 5, -8]` and the sorted's sums would be (as expected): `[5, -1, -8]`

Is there some sort of crate for this function, or should I write my own if it doesn't exist?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort_by_key - is this what you need?

Comment: You cannot sort generic iterators, because they do not allow random access. But you can sort a vector or a slice with [`sort_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_by) and friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are searching for is `sort_by_key`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct PointTracker {
    positive: u32,
    negative: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut item = vec![
        PointTracker {
            positive: 3,
            negative: 4,
        },
        PointTracker {
            positive: 5,
            negative: 0,
        },
        PointTracker {
            positive: 2,
            negative: 10,
        },
    ];

    item.sort_by_key(|x| x.positive as i32 - x.negative as i32);

    println!("{:#?}", item);
}
```

Output:

```
[
    PointTracker {
        positive: 2,
        negative: 10,
    },
    PointTracker {
        positive: 3,
        negative: 4,
    },
    PointTracker {
        positive: 5,
        negative: 0,
    },
]
```

Comment: To add to this, the differences between `sort_by_key` and [sort_unstable_by_key](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_unstable_by_key) might be worth mentioning or a crate such as `Itertools` doing what the author had in mind, see: [`sorted_by_key()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.sorted_by_key)
and [`sorted_unstable_by_key()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.sorted_unstable_by_key).

Comment: Major thumbs up for this, Jason, and huge thanks to Rabbid76. For some reason, `sort_by_key` wasn't giving me the results I needed, so I switched over to using `itertools` and I got exactly the implementation I wanted.